# Count the number of lines from point A to point B in Text File

Tags: java, loops, io, count, text-files

I am trying to figure out how to find the first instance of a string in a given text file, start counting the number of lines starting from the first line with that instance of the string, then stop counting when another/different string is found in a new line.

Basically I have a text file like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "dba".check_diff(a smallint,
                             b       int, 
                             c       int,
                             d  smallint,
                             e smallint,
                             f   smallint,
                             g   smallint,
                             h     smallint,
                             i    smallint)

RETURNING int;
DEFINE p_ret int;
LET p_ret = 0;

END IF;

RETURN p_ret;

END PROCEDURE;
```

And I just want to find the first instance of "CREATE PROCEDURE" and increment a variable until I reach the instance of "END PROCEDURE;", then reset the variable.

What I have been trying is...

```
import java.io.*;

public class countFile 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      try
      {
          int i = 0;
          // Open the file that is the first 
          // command line parameter
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/results.txt");
          // Stream to write file
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/count_results.txt");     
          // Get the object of DataInputStream
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;
          //Read File Line By Line
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
          {
              if (strLine.contains("CREATE PROCEDURE"))
              {
                  while (!strLine.contains("END PROCEDURE;"))
                  {
                      i++;
                      break;
                  }
                  new PrintStream(fout).println (i);
              }
          }
          //Close the input stream
          in.close();
          fout.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          //Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

However, that just counts the total number of instances of "CREATE PROCEDURE" and writes out the variable i each time it gets incremented...not what I'm looking for.

Any help?

**SOLUTION FOUND**:

```
import java.io.*;

public class countFile 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      try
      {
          int i = 0;
          boolean isInProcedure = false;
          // Open the file that is the first 
          // command line parameter
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/results.txt");
          // Stream to write file
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/count_results.txt");     
          // Get the object of DataInputStream
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;
          // Read File Line By Line
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
          {
              // If the line contains create procedure...
              if (strLine.contains("CREATE PROCEDURE")) 
              {
                  // Set this flag to true
                  isInProcedure = true;
              }
              // If the line contains end procedure, stop counting...
              if (strLine.contains("END PROCEDURE;")) 
              {
                 // Write to the new file
                 new PrintStream(fout).println(i);
                 // Set flag to false
                 isInProcedure = false;
                 // Reset counter
                 i = 0;
              }
              // Used to count lines between create procedure and end procedure
              else
              {
                  if (isInProcedure == true)
                  {
                      //Increment the counter for each line
                      i++;
                  }
              }
          }
          //Close the input stream
          in.close();
          fout.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          //Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (br.ready()) {
   if (br.readLine().contains("CREATE PROCEDURE")) {
      while (!br.readLine().contains("END PROCEDURE;")) {
         i++;
      }
    }
    new PrintStream(fout).println(i);
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to give me an accurate count. Just wrote out "1" multiple times. :(

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer Ohh... sorry, right now it works fine, try this one

Comment: Haha, that just seemed to throw it in an infinite loop where i is never incremented, i.e. 0 is just printed out over and over again.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer sorry for my english, i don't understand you, this works right or not?

Comment: No, it did not work, it resulted in an infinite loop. :(

But I was able to figure out a solution a little while ago, and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "c:\\test.txt" ) );

            String line;
            Boolean count = false;
            Integer lines = 0;

            while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                if ( line.toUpperCase().contains( "CREATE PROCEDURE" ) )
                {
                    count = true;
                }

                if ( line.toUpperCase().contains( "END PROCEDURE;" ) )
                {
                    break;
                }

                if ( count == true )
                {
                    lines++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println( lines );
        }
        catch ( Exception exception )
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this did not seem to work either. It just gave me what looked like a total count of the different instances of "Create Procedure" which is not what I was looking for :(. But thank you still.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer What? It gives an output of 18. This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Maybe I worded my question poorly? I basically had multiple statements beginning with "create procedure" and "end procedure" and I needed to count the lines between each of those two lines for multiple statements in a text file. I ultimately did find the solution, thanks in part to your post though.